# Escape HTML tags and print code to screen

Tags: html

I want the following to be displayed on the screen: < / develop >

However, when I try to place it in my html, it is interpreted as an end tag.

How do I escape regular html tags and write these characters as text to be printed to the screen?

Answer (score 2):

Using HTML Entities:

```
&lt;/developer&gt;
```

ref: http://www.htmlentities.com/html/entities/

HTML has reserved special characters, so you you use the appropriate HTML entity to emit them to the screen. It can also be useful when you are trying to print out characters outside of the normal ASCII set and you want to be assured they will render correctly irrespective of the browser's character encoding setting.

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
&lt; /develop&gt;
```